# Recursive reduce in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, recursion, reduce

I'm quite new to JavaScript and don't understand a few of its behaviours. I want to write a recursive version of reduce function found in [Eloquent JavaScript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/) book. That's my code:

```
function rec_reduce( fn, base, list ) {
    if( list.length === 0 ) {
        return base;
    }
    else {
        rec_reduce( fn, fn( base, list[ 0 ] ), list.slice( 1 ) );
    }
}
print( rec_reduce( Math.min, 100, [ 5, 3, 7, 2, 6, 5 ] ));
```

The result was:

```
undefined
```

To see what's going on I put:

```
print( base );
```

as a first line of the function and the result was:

```
100
5
3
3
2
2
2
undefined
```

Whould anyone explain me why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In that `else` block, you'll have to

```
return rec_reduce( ... )
```

Comment: THX A LOT!! I forget about this return thing now and then mainly because every thime I need something recursive I prototype it in Scheme - there's no return statement ;) Thx again!

Comment: @trzewiczek Care to accept, then? Suits *your* profile well, too.

Comment: Sorry about that - it's just I'm not experienced - forgot about that!!

Answer (score 4):

Another way to do it:

**reduce_file.js:**

```
function reduce(arr, func, initv){
      if(arr.length) return reduce(arr.slice(1), func, func(initv, arr[0]))
      else return initv
}
module.exports = reduce
```

and then you use it as:

```
reduce = require('./reduce_file.js')
console.log(reduce([1,2,3,4], function(prev, curr) {
  return prev + curr
}, 0))
```

result:

```
10
```

from 1+2+3+4=10